# store select result

Tags: c#

i want to extract my table names and save it into variables this is my cod that return 3 answer:student, teacher and score. how can i change it to save these tree table name to 3 variable. thank you.

```
try
{
  SqlDataReader myreader = null;
  SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("select * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'", myconnect);
  myreader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
  while (myreader.Read())
  {
    Console.WriteLine(myreader[2].ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: If you already know the answer to the query why get it from the database? Just set three variables with the appropriate values, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple builtin way is using [`Connection.GetSchema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254934%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
using (var con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    con.Open();
    DataTable schemaTable = con.GetSchema("Tables");
    IList<string> allTableNames = schemaTable.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => r.Field<string>("TABLE_TYPE") == "BASE TABLE")
        .Select(r => r.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME"))
        .ToList();
}
```

Now you have a `List<string>` with all table names which you can access via indexer or in a loop or create a comma separated list with `string.Join`:

```
string tNames = string.Join(",", allTableNames);
Console.Write("all tables in the given database: " + tNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
string tableName ="" ; // Variable to stroe the table names
string connectionString = ""; //Your connectionstring
// get records from the table
string commandString =""; //Your query
// create the data set command object
// and the DataSet
SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter =new SqlDataAdapter(commandString, connectionString);
DataSet DataSet = new DataSet( );

// fill the DataSet object
DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "Customers");
// Get the one table from the DataSet
DataTable dataTable = DataSet.Tables[0];
// for each row in the table, display the info
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
 {

  tableName = dataRow[0].tostring();
  //...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save the result for future user or a different session then you can use any of the following to methods

first one
use the "insert" query to save the result one by one in the a different table that you would create specially for saving the data 
you can put the insert command/statement directly into the for loop

second method
use the xml to store the value very simple and memory friendly

Answer (score 0):

I Have modified @Doctor code to use ArrayList to store number of table name in single variables.

```
ArrayList alTableName  = new ArrayList(); // Variable to stroe the table names
string connectionString = ""; //Your connectionstring
// get records from the table
string commandString =""; //Your query
// create the data set command object
// and the DataSet

SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter =new SqlDataAdapter(commandString, connectionString);
DataSet DataSet = new DataSet( );

// fill the DataSet object
DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "Customers");

// Get the one table from the DataSet
DataTable dataTable = DataSet.Tables[0];

// for each row in the table, display the info
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
{

    alTableName.Add(dataRow[0].tostring());
    //...
}
```